# Polling for updates in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to poll for updated entries in the database using an Angular2 front-end. I was able to get polling to work succesfully, but on each poll request the response would include the entire list of objects in the DB table, creating some very expensive polling requests. I would like to be able to keep track of what I've already gotten and just poll for updates.

My initial thought was just to keep track of the object ID's and just keep requesting for ID's greater than the current highest. Problem is I don't know how to make the Observable.interval update what the request with my updated ID value.

```
this.incidentsService
  .loadIncidentsWithIdGreaterThan(this.highestId)
  .subscribe((incidents) => {
    this.incidents = incidents;
    this.highestId = incidents[this.incidents.length - 1].id;    
  });

loadIncidentsWithIdGreaterThan(id: number) : Observable<Incident[]> {
return Observable.interval(2000)
  .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.url + "/idGreaterThan/" + id)
    .map((data) => data.json() as Incident[]));
}
```

When I go in chrome console I can see that we're still getting all the DB objects and that the polling request is still using "1" for ID and not updating. Is there a way I can get around this or a different strategy for this type of thing?

Comment: Why can't you just do `.switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.url + "/idGreaterThan/" + this.highestId)` instead of trying to pass the id in?

Comment: Ok that seemed to work, however that forces me to have all that code in my incidents page whereas I'd really like to have part of that code in an incidents service. Surely there is a way I can do this?